# Mysterious white space on right side of website — tried everything

Tags: html, css, drupal

I run a `multilingual Drupal 7 website`. White space recently appeared on the right side. I can't find the cause. It shows up on the [German home page](http://perlen-poesie.com/de) but not when you switch to English, unless one logs in. It inconsistently appears throughout the website. It shows up in every major browser **except Firefox.**

I've combed through the `css and html`, but I'm missing something here. Can someone please take a look?

`"overflow-x: hidden"` **is not really a solution for me — I would like to pinpoint the cause.**

Here's a [CodePen Link](http://codepen.io/fatmarker/pen/Bprec/).

Comment: Please post your HTMl/CSS here and if possible a JSFiddle/CodePen/jsbin link

Comment: I don't know which area of the page or which code is the cause. To paste all of it would be immensely long.

Comment: I don't see white space on the right side for either page, btw. Without code it's a shot in the dark for helping you even if we could reproduce the error.

Comment: Both look fine to me.  Maybe your resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the following class causing the issue:

element-invisible

It is used on the h2 header here:

Sekundärmenü

To see for yourself, just do a rename on the element and you will see it fixes the issue.

Comment: Just for the record the uk site doesn't use that class, which is why it looks fine.

Comment: You are a blessing! Thank you!! How did you find it? Inspector and Firebug weren't giving me any clues.

Comment: Usually i use web developer tools on firefox, but in this case, i shifted through the html, chopping sections out until i got it down to a small section of code.  Glad it's sorted.